# How do i get EventListener to find a certain class when it's having trouble?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typeerror, navbar

I am working on a responsive navigation bar and have basically gotten everything to work besides a small javascript click even error im getting in my sub menu.

I have gone through my index, script, and style files and cannot find a specific reason why EventListener is getting null when looking for the specified class.

The HTML code i am trying to select a class from:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Uncle Jeffs Pack</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <!-- Boxicons CSS -->
        <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <div class="navbar">
                <i class='bx bx-menu'></i>
                <div class="logo"><a href="#">UJP</a></div>
                <div class="nav-links">
                    <div class="sidebar-logo">
                        <span class="logo_name">UJP</span>
                        <i class='bx bx-x'></i>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="links">
                        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">PHOTOS</a>
                            <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow photos-arrow'></i>
                            <ul class="photos-sub-menu sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Drop 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Drop 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Drop 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Drop 4</a></li>
                                <li class="more">
                                    <a href="#">More</a>
                                    <i class='bx bxs-chevron-right arrow more-arrow'></i>
                                    <ul class="more-sub-menu sub-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Drop 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Drop 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Drop 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Drop 4</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">BLOGS</a>
                            <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow blogs-arrow'></i>
                            <ul class="blogs-sub-menu sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Drop 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Drop 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Drop 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Drop 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="search-box">
                    <i class='bx bx-search-alt-2'></i>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="main-paragraph">
            <h2>Hello World</h2>
        </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i apply the following code to my script.js i get an error in the console: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener)

```
let navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
let searchBox = document.querySelector(".search-box .bx-search-alt-2");
//<i class='bx bx-x'></i>
searchBox.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    navbar.classList.toggle("showInput");
    if(navbar.classList.contains("showInput")){
        searchBox.classList.replace("bx-search-alt-2","bx-x");
    }else {
        searchBox.classList.replace("bx-x", "bx-search");
    }
});


// sidebar open close js code
let menuOpenBtn = document.querySelector(".navbar .bx-menu");
let closeOpenBtn = document.querySelector('.nav-links .bx-x');
let navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links");

menuOpenBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    navLinks.style.left="0";
});
closeOpenBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    navLinks.style.left="-100%";
});
```

After doing some research i understand this could be due to the script running before the DOM is fully loaded. That is why i added "window.onload=function()" but even with that i still cannot get it to work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: It's `.photos-arrow` (you forgot the dot).

Comment: You have no elements with the ID or classname of photos-arrow in your snippet. And as @Robo Robok stated, you need either a `.` or `#` in the `querySelector`, depending on whether it's an ID or classname. Furthermore, you have not defined a variable called `navLinks` in your JS. `window.onload` is not needed.

Comment: @SigurdMazanti `"<i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow photos-arrow'></i>"`?

Comment: You all are amazing thank you. I am so sorry for the stupid mistake. This will not happen again.

Comment: @JPCodes no worries, I find myself forgetting about the dot in selectors too from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robo Robok is right. Beat me to it. `".photos-arrow"`